# Registro de controller angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

Tenho esse app e esse html:

https://jsfiddle.net/2r4w554g/

E tenho também esse controller e esse html:

https://jsfiddle.net/oes9vzu8/1/

Quando coloco pra rodar, ele me aponta um erro de que o controller não foi encontrado. Porém, se eu tirar o controller da view e colocar no index, ele funciona. Ou seja, ele não está localizando o arquivo do controller.
Alguém tem alguma idéia de como resolver?

Comment: Coloque o código referente à sua questão diretamente na pergunta. Não utilize algum site externo para isso, pois se o site sair do ar ou coisas do tipo, não teremos como acessar seu código.

Comment: Fora colocar o código do fiddle na pergunta, acho que você deveria tentar explicar melhor seu problema. Não deu pra entender.

Comment: Já tentou fazer o `load` do arquivo do `controller` direto na index ao invés de fazer o `load` pela `tag` dentro do `html` específico do `controller`? Provavelmente isso vai resolver o problema, já que para fazer um "lazyload", que é o que parece que está tentando fazer, você precisaria de outros plugins,